# How to import data file into PieCloudDB?

Tags: database

When I try to import csv file into PieCloudDB,there's error showing:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg9ru.png).The data file is correct,how can I fix this?

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your data file contains a header that was identified as data.Checking this option in advanced options when importing data file.In PieCloudDB, this setting is hidden in advanced options.
[image]